# Keep track of NSTimer firings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I'd like to keep track of how many times an NSTimer fires and store the number in an ivar. I have a pointer to an NSTimer stored in a property called `timer` that I've set like so: `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(method) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`

Any pointers out there on how to keep track of how many times `timer` fires and store the number in an instance variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an instance variable `timerCount` and then put `timerCount++` into your timer method.